# Convertir 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' a 'hh:mm:ss tt', SQL Server

Tags: datetime, conversión-de-tipos, sql-server-2008-r2

Suponiendo que tengo las siguientes Fecha/Hora en una `tabla` de la Base de Datos:

> **Entrada** : `05/03/2018 08:00:00.000` 
>   , **Salida** : `05/03/2018 18:00:00.000`

Necesito obtener la siguiente salida:

`Entrada`: **08:00:00 a.m.**

`Salida`:  **06:00:00 p.m.**

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
select case when datepart(hour,entrada) > 12 then convert(varchar(28), cast(entrada as datetime), 8) + ' p.m.'
else convert(varchar(30), cast(entrada as datetime) , 8) + ' a.m.' end as hora_entrada,
case when datepart(hour,salida) > 12 then convert(varchar(28), cast(salida as datetime), 8) + ' p.m.'
else convert(varchar(30), cast(salida as datetime) , 8) + ' a.m.' end as hora_salida,
right(convert(varchar(20),entrada,113),9) as entrada,
right(convert(varchar(20),salida,113),9) as salida
from tablaX
```

El resultado obtenido es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar la salida esta mal `18:00:00 p.m.`.

**¿Cómo puedo hacerlo sin usar tantas conversiones?**

**Entorno:** SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Qué tipo de datos son las columnas entrada y salida originalmente?

Comment: @Lamak Las columnas son `DateTime`

Comment: Esta formateo de hora generalmente se realiza en la aplicacion que consume este dato (app web, movil, api, reporte, etc) ya que alli es donde la hora o fecha debe "culturizarse" en el formato que el cliente lo requiera (o por default de la app)

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez si me parece que es una mejor idea hacerlo directamente en la aplicación que lo requiere.

Comment: Que tipo de app estas utilizando? En que lenguaje? asi te podremos ayudar mejor

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez gracias, lo resolví con la respuesta que publique, aunque como implica muchas conversiones opte por resolverlo en la parte de la aplicación, lo hice en el `C#` , gracias por tomarte el tiempo de atender a la pregunta.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez te dejo un enlace que te puede ayudar [Cadenas con formato de fecha y hora personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si alguien lo necesita, al final ha quedado de esta forma:

Solución 1:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
              STUFF(
                RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(
                  RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(40),
                    CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018/03/05 18:00:00.000'),109),14)),14),9,4,' '),
             'PM',
             ' p.m.'),
            'AM',
            ' a.m.') as hora_entrada
```

Solución 2:

```
SELECT  REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                RIGHT(
                    '0000000000' + 
                        CONVERT(
                        varchar(10), 
                        cast('2018/03/05 18:00:00.000' as time(0)), 
                        109),
                10), 
            'PM', 
            ' p.m.'),
        'AM',
        ' a.m.') as hora_entrada
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo único que necesitas es epecificar el formato de salida, que para el caso es un `TIME` (NO `DATETIME`, por ende primero hay que convertirlo a tal) y con formato 100 (puedes ver muchos ejemplos diferentes [aquí](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)).

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(entrada AS TIME), 100) AS hora_entrada,
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(salida AS TIME), 100) AS hora_salida,
right(convert(varchar(20),entrada,113),9) as entrada,
right(convert(varchar(20),salida,113),9) as salida
from tablaX
```

Comment: Funciona pero la salida es: `8:00AM` y `6:00PM` , y por cuestión de formato en todo el sistema necesito que se muestre así: `08:00:00 a.m.` y `06:00:00 p.m.` con todas las cifras y las letras minúsculas incluyendo los puntos. Debe haber una forma de hacerlo posible

Comment: Si luego de obtener el valor pudiera hacer algo como esto: `FORMAT(CAST(entrada AS DATETIME),'hh:mm:ss tt')  as hora_entrada` pero la función **FORMAT** no la reconoce en SQL 2008